# SEO Friendly URL in CakePHP pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm using CakePHP v2.42 & would like to have SEO friendly URL in page pagination.

My current pagination is like

http://www.website.com/ubs/page/page:2

What to do to change to

http://www.website.com/ubs/page/2

My Controller is

```
<?php
  class UbsController extends AppController {

  public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

  public function index() {

    $this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 100,
    );

    $ubs = $this->paginate();

    $this->set('ubs', $ubs);
}}
```

My Router is

```
Router::connect('/ubs', array('controller' => 'ubs', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/ubs/page/*', array('controller' => 'ubs', 'action' => 'index'));
```

**EDIT - ADD MORE QUESTION**

Answer by @kicaj is perfectly correct for the Router & Controller. However, the navigation link only display correctly on the first page.

In the first page navigation link show like this which is correct

```
http://www.website.com/ubs/
http://www.website.com/ubs/page/2/
http://www.website.com/ubs/page/3/
```

But navigation link show like this in second/third page page

```
http://www.website.com/ubs/index/2/
http://www.website.com/ubs/index/2/page:3/
```

I guess need to edit index.ctp file but not sure what to do.

My current navigation link in index.ctp show like this

```
$paginator = $this->Paginator;
$paginator->prev("« Prev");
$paginator->numbers(array('modulus' => 200, 'separator' => ' '));
$paginator->next("Next »");
```

What to change to correct this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Router::connect('/ubs/page/:page', array(
    'controller' => 'ubs',
    'action' => 'index'
), array(
    'pass' => array(
        'page'
    ),
    'page' => '[\d]+'
));
```

and in index action in ubs controller add code bellow:

```
public function index($page = 1) {
    // ...
    $this->request->params['named']['page'] = $page;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: TQVM... The code work perfectly for the Router & Controller. However, the navigation link only show correctly on the first page. Second & subsequent page the navigation does not display correctly. I edit the question to describe the problem. Please take a look..

Comment: Try add in view, before $paginator->prev():  `$paginator->options(array('url'=> array('controller' => 'ubs','action' => 'index')));`

Comment: I try understand: Your links not generated correctly, but when You put address in browser (like e.g: http://www.website.com/ubs/page/3/) then pagination works?

Comment: If I put in the link like website.com/ubs/page/3 in the browser, it works correctly. Only problem with the navigation link.

Comment: OK problem solve...after I add add $paginator->options(array('url'=> array('controller' => 'ubs','action' => 'index'))); before $paginator->prev(); TQVM

Answer (score 0):

In your Paginator Helper you can choose the right friendly url you want with setting some options

- `url` The URL of the paginating action. ‘url’ has a few sub options as well:

  - `sort` The key that the records are sorted by.
  - `direction` The direction of the sorting. Defaults to ‘ASC’.
  - `page` The page number to display.

There here an example .

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'url' => array(
        'sort' => 'email', 'direction' => 'desc', 'page' => 6,
        'lang' => 'en'
    )
));
```

the source : [Modifying the options PaginatorHelper uses](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#modifying-the-options-paginatorhelper-uses)

Comment: TQ for helping. I manage to get the solution from response from kicaj above